# How can I make a bash script run when files are added to a directory?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, curl, cron

I have a bash script running on my Mac that uses cURL to upload files to a remote Ubuntu server. I currently run the script on a 1 minute interval with a cronjob, and then append uploaded files with a "_uploaded" flag. I would love to avoid using the cronjob and just have a script "listen" to the directory and upload files only as they're added. Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about this? Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add a Folder Action. Right click on the directory in the Finder then associate a script with the folder. See e.g. http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/01/30/folder-actions-for-os-x-explained-with-real-world-examples/

Comment: Does this work even if the file is not added via Finder (e.g. will the action(s) run if I copy a file in using `cp`)?

Comment: Yes, I just tested in on OS X 10.6 to be sure that it works with both Finder drags and with `cp` etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can use inotify kernel hooks. Ubuntu server has wrapper: inotify-tools package

Comment: I think he needs something for Mac OS X, not for the Ubuntu server.